# How do I find the last record my database table using PDO?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

How can I execute this using PDO? I use MySQL for my database. I am trying to call the last `infog_id`.

```
$q = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM Infographic ORDER BY infog_id DESC LIMIT 1");
$q->fetchAll();
```

Comment: If you want just `infog_id`, then why are you doing `SELECT *` && `fetchAll()`. Just do `$q = $conn->query("SELECT infog_id FROM Infographic ORDER BY infog_id DESC LIMIT 1"); $result = $q->fetch(); echo $result['infog_id'];`

Comment: Are you asking for a better SQL statement above? Or are you asking how to connect to a MySQL database via PDO in PHP?

Comment: Use `max` if the column is auto-incrementing. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-maximum-column.html

Answer (score 7):

Similar to what Sean said, if you only need one column, don't get all of them.

```
$q = $conn->query("SELECT infog_id FROM Infographic ORDER BY infog_id DESC LIMIT 1");
$infog_id = $q->fetchColumn();
```

fetchColumn() by default retrieves the first column from the next available row, for this query, this will be infog_id.

If you actually want the whole row, use fetch().

```
$q = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM Infographic ORDER BY infog_id DESC LIMIT 1");
$row = $q->fetch();
```

fetch() returns the next available row, in this case, there is only one (LIMIT 1).